# How to insert form value in ci?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

controller: Test.php

```
<?php
class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->model('Users_model');
        $this->Users_model->insert_user();
        $this->load->view('home');
    }
}
```

?>

Model: User_model.php

```
<?php
    class Users_model extends CI_Model
    {
        public function insert_user()
        {    
            $data = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'message' => $this->input->post('message')
            );
            return $this->db->insert('user', $data);
        }   
    }
?>
```

view: home.php

```
<form method="post">
    <label for="name">your Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" />

    <label for="email">Your email</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" />

    <label for="message">Your Message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

I am new in codeigniter here I want to insert form value into database but it showing some error i.e.

[image]

how can I fix this error ? please help.

Thank You

Comment: In order to debug I would suggest using `var_dump($data);
die;` or `print_r($data);
die;` before ` return $this->db->insert('user', $data);` in order to check that the model has the data as is appears the data is null.

Comment: No need on controller, models to use `?>` at the end in codeigniter https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#php-closing-tag

Comment: it return Array ( [name] => [email] => [message] => ) @max gilbert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the errors because you call `User_model->insert_user()` before any data submitted in the form. You should check if there is any posted data then save to the database. Here is the example of your controller should be:

```html
<?php
class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->model('Users_model');
        
        // do checking right here
        if (!empty($this->input->post('name'))) {
            $this->Users_model->insert_user();
        }
        
        $this->load->view('home');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You forget to pass POST data in insert method of model in controller .**

*Contoller*

```
 <?php
    class Test extends CI_Controller {
        public function index()
        {
$data = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'message' => $this->input->post('message')
            );
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->model('Users_model');
            $this->Users_model->insert_user($data );
            $this->load->view('home');
        }
    }
```

*Model*

```
<?php
    class Users_model extends CI_Model
    {
        public function insert_user($data = [])
        {    

            return $this->db->insert('user', $data);
        }   
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You extend **CI_Model** But did not call parent construct. Use this:

```
    function __construct() {
       // Call the Model constructor
       parent :: __construct();
    }
```

Hope this will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your "home.php" you haven't specify an action attribute. Due to this form value is not posting.

for example:- `<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>YourfileName/DeclaredFunctionName" method="post">`

and then try to fetch the value of your form in your controller.

In controller please execute this `function insert_user() { print_r($_POST); exit(); }`

If you are getting values in your browser, then remove exit() and execute your code. Otherwise, please share your error here.

Thanks